# Get list file in a folder and subfolders

Tags: vba

I would like to get file name in a Folder and its subfolder, so I wrote the code like this:

```
Sub list_folder()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim folder As folder
    Dim file As file
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    Dim myfolder As folder
    Dim i As Long: i = 2
    'Dim lastrowB As Long
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\test")
    For Each myfolder In folder.SubFolders
        Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = myfolder.Name
            For Each file In myfolder.Files
                Sheet1.Range("B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value = file.Name
            Next file
        i = i + Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Next myfolder
End Sub
```

I wish column A will show Folder name, and column B will show the file name. But with the above code, it just shows subfolders, can not get the file list. Could you please assist with this?

Below is my material for test code

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```vb
Sub list_folder()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim file As file
    Dim myfolder As folder
    Dim i As Long

    i = 2    
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    For Each myfolder In fso.GetFolder("C:\test").SubFolders
        Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = myfolder.Name 'if listing once only
        For Each file In myfolder.Files
                'Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = myfolder.Name '...or for each file
                Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Row).Value = file.Name
                i=i+1
        Next file
    Next myfolder
End Sub
```